# Could not load type from another project in same assembly ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three asp.net mvc 5 projects in one solution. The solution is called `Bank24` so the assembly too. Project `Application_layer` is main project. Also there is 2 more projects. There are `BusinessLogic_layer` where I'm working with database and `Data layer` where I'm creating database.

When I attempting to use class from `BusinessLogic_layer` in `Application_layer` I'm getting runtime server error -

> Could not load type "BusinessLogic_layer.Services.DataService" from assembly "Bank24, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null"

Project `Application_layer` already has reference to `BusinessLogic_layer`. Directory that contains needed class already linked with `Using` directive. So I don't know why it doesen't loading.

Here is code of Controller `MainController`. I need to use desired class in method `Register`. It is linked with `using BusinessLogic_layer.Services;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Application_layer.Models;
using BusinessLogic_layer.Services;

namespace Application_layer.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class MainController : Controller
{

    ...

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void Register()
    {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "Admin" };
            var result = UserManager.Create(user, "q1w2e3");
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                DataService dataWorker = new DataService();
                dataWorker.CreateUser("Admin", "Суренко Иван Васильевич", 0);
                RedirectToAction("Login", "Authorization");
            }
    }
}
}
```

Here is code of `DataService` class which is in `Services` folder of another project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BusinessLogic_layer.Models;
using Data_layer.DataAccess;
using Data_layer.Models;

namespace BusinessLogic_layer.Services
{
public class DataService
{
    ...

    public void CreateUser(string login, string name, byte role)
    {
        bool isEmployee = false;
        if (role == 0)
            isEmployee = true;
        BankContext db = new BankContext();
        db.Users.Add(new User() { Login = login, Name = name, Role = role, IsEmployee = isEmployee });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    ...

}
}
```

P.S. I have Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Check the target .NET Framework for each project. If, for example, your `Application_Layer` targets 4.0 and your `Business_Layer` targets 4.5, you would receive an error similar to this, even though the reference is set correctly and the namespaces are also used correctly.

Comment: @AlexBarac The target .NET Framework for all projects is 4.5. I've ckecked it before asking.

Comment: could you please provide a screenshot of structure?

Comment: @kkocabiyik @AlexBarac I`ve solved this problem. I started new project and begun testing. After a couple of hours I found several things. 1. Projects must be in different assemblys. I don't know why CLR could not load type when they are in same assembly. 2. It follows from 1 - all projects except main project must have `empty template` type. So thank you for advises but I`ve already solved this. P.S. I've finally found how to highlight text with gray background, hooray.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. I started new project and begun testing. After a couple of hours I found several things. 1. Projects must be in different assemblys nevertheless they can be in one solution. I don't know why CLR could not load type when they are in same assembly. 2. It follows from 1 - all projects except main project must have `empty project` type.